# How to add optional parameter in JPQL?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

How to use/add optional parameter in JPQL?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT stud FROM Student stud where stud.name = :studentName AND stud.age IN :studentAgeList")
List<Student> getStudents(
            @Param("studentName ") String studentName, 
            @Param("studentAgeList") List<Integer> studentAgeList
         )
```

How to make studentAgeList parameter in above query ?

I tried below :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT stud FROM Student stud where stud.name = :studentName AND (:studentAgeList IS NULL OR stud.age IN :studentAgeList))
List<Student> getStudents(
            @Param("studentName ") String studentName, 
            @Param("studentAgeList") List<Integer> studentAgeList
         )
```

But getting error : **unexpected AST node:**

Tried above but getting error

Comment: I've tried it and the only problem I get is when I set an empty list in `studentAgeList` parameter. If I set NULL or a non-empty list, it works correctly. Could you show your stack trace ?

Comment: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: unexpected AST node: {vector}

Comment: This exception occurs when the program starts during JPA initialization or when you call the method `getStudents()` ?

Comment: getting this  when calling the getStudent()

Comment: Precisely, with what value for `studentAgeList` ?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69610579/unexpected-ast-node-vector-in-spring-data-jpa. I think you will find a solution using `coalesce(:studentAgeList) is null`

Answer (score 0):

JPQL does not support optional parameters, you can use overload methods with different queries or criteria API or JPA specifications.

may be get answer here: [Set optional parameters in JPQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569238/set-optional-parameters-in-jpql-query)

Comment: Indeed, there could be 2 query methods defined (with or without the student list) but the question was more about the possibility to build a where clause testing the parameter it self.